# Trying to understand the logics of linux iptables

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, ping

I'm trying to understand the logic behind the iptables rules below. I know that we are allowing our machine to be pinged on eth0 with the rule " -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT ", however for the rule " -A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP ", are we stating to drop any other request on eth0 that are not icmp?

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 2):

in a word. yes. iptables rules are considered top to bottom, so assuming there's no other rules prior to these, the only traffic allowed will be of icmp protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Yes any packet which is intended for this system and it not an icmp packet, then it will be dropped by INPUT chain of filter table.